# How to map distinct values from collectionA to collectionB persistently? Meteor Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is there any way I can get all the unique values of a particular field in a mongodb say collectionA and map it across to say collectionB whilst maintaining that if collectionA gets another new entry, collectionB is automatically updated?

```
so if collectionA has the following: 
{ itemCode: "aaa", purchaseOrder: "po1" }`
{ itemCode: "aaa", purchaseOrder: "po2" }
{ itemCode: "bbb", purchaseOrder: "po3" }

collectionB should have 
{ itemCode: "aaa" }
{ itemCode: "bbb" }
```

if an entry goes into collectionA `{ itemCode: "ccc", purchaseOrder: "po4" }`

```
collectionB automatically gets updated with
{ itemCode: "aaa" }
{ itemCode: "bbb" }
{ itemCode: "ccc" }
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: No. No triggers, no events. But you can get the distinct item codes on demand: `db.collectionA.distinct("itemCode")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part you can do by just using `.upsert()` to avoid dupes:

```
const A = CollectionA.find();
A.map( a => {
  const itemCode = a.itemCode;
  CollectionB.upsert({ itemCode },{ $set: { itemCode });      
});
```

You can optimize this further by first finding the unique values of `itemCode` using [_.uniq()](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) and/or finding only those elements of A that don't already have a value in B.

The second bit can be done with an observer.

```
A.observe({
  added(a){
    const itemCode = a.itemCode;
    CollectionB.upsert({ itemCode },{ $set: { itemCode });
  }
});
```

Here again we use `.upsert()` to avoid dupes.

Comment: With your query `CollectionA.find().map( a => {...` will this return a cursor including the `.map()` query? Or just the `collection.find()` I'm confused because I'm not sure how do you observe the entire query with the `.map()...` part...

Comment: You're right. The collection needs to be separated out to be reused in the observer.

Comment: I tested out the solution you provided. By simply using the `upsert()` you can already get all distinct values, I am unsure if it is O(n) complexity, because I don't know what the efficiency of `upsert()` is, but I don't think I'll go too far to optimize the solution. Thanks @MichelFloyd for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use collectionA.map(a => a.itemCode) instead of collectionB.

I don't think reference mapping is an option by itself.

Also, you're just duplicating data in your case.